# Perderei meus bancos de dados se atualizar o SQL Server 2012 Express para o Standard?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho instalado uma instancia 2012 Express, preciso atualizar para o Standard, mas para atualizar preciso ter certeza de que não haverá nenhuma alteração nos bancos de dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em tese não terá problemas, há compatibilidade total.

Mas se está inseguro, faça um teste antes para ter certeza. Na verdade você pode perder por manobras erradas. Então é bom fazer com cuidado, testar antes em ambiente fora de produção, ter *backup* se precisar voltar atrás.

Comment: Apenas complementando... Para o backup: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187510(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Não.

[Este link ensina a fazer os passos de instalação](http://blog.fpweb.net/sql-express-to-sql-server-standard-in-place-upgrade/#.VfsW_N9VhBc). Em todo caso, recomendo um *backup* de *schema* + dados. [Há um passo-a-passo para isso aqui](http://www.serverintellect.com/support/sqlserver/database-backup-ssmse/).

Answer (score 2):

Todas as vezes que instalei diferentes versões do SQL Server, lado-a-lado, elas sempre coexistiram sem tocar os dados umas das outras. Aliás, já imaginou quanta gente distraída iria perder seus dados acidentalmente se esse não fosse o caso? A fúria dos DBAs contra a Microsoft? :)

Mas já reza o ditado, *seguro morreu de velho*.

Mesmo que todos os manuais, explicações e testes funcionem sem perder dados, você deve fazer o que é sempre recomendado para manutenção de banco de dados: **backup**.

O mundo real é cruel e, por mais que você tente seguir os passos corretos para não perder seus dados (por completo ou parcialmente), a Lei de Murphy é nossa eterna adversária e um dia ela entra em ação.

O recomendado é não só tirar backup do seu banco mas também testar o procedimento de restauração regularmente, para não descobrir que os backups não prestam só na hora que precisar.